# finding average scores in python

Tags: python, lambda

I have some code which gets a list from a text file and puts it into a dictionary. This is the code:

```
fd = open('Results.txt')
lines = [line.strip() for line in fd]
adict = {}
for line in lines:
  splitted = [i for i in line.split(',')]
  key = splitted[0]
  adict[key] = splitted[1:]
s = addict
```

Then, using this, I find the top marks and the top average score from the results which are in this list. My current code is:

```
avg_mark = lambda name:sum(s[name])/len(s[name])
for i in sorted(s.keys(),key=avg_mark,reverse=True):
    print (i,avg_mark(i),"\n")
```

However, it says:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Can anyone fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data read from a file is returned as *strings*, but `sum()` by default expects *numeric values*. You'l need to convert your data to numbers first.

You can use `int()` or `float()` to convert numeric values:

```
adict[key] = [float(n) for n in splitted[1:]]
```

You appear to be reading CSV data; consider using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to parse the file instead:

```
import csv

with open('Results.txt', 'r', newline='') as fd:
    reader = csv.reader(fd)
    s = {row[0]: [float(c) for c in row[1:]] for row in reader}
```

If your first column is *quoted*, you can even have the `csv.reader()` do the string-to-float conversion for you; using [`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) when creating the `csv.reader()` object will result in anything that doesn't use `"` around the column value to be passed to your Python code as a `float()`.